# Concatenating Keras Dense to Conv2D output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation

Suppose I have two layers I want to concatenate: (Dense) called outg and (Conv2D) called outm with output shapes of (None, 256) and (None, 32, 32, 256). My goal is to merge the outputs into shape (None, 32, 32, 512). Picture below for better understanding. Blue region represents Conv2D and orange regions represent repeated Dense layer output.
[image]

My thought is to use `RepeatVector, Reshape and Concatenate` from `keras.layers`, so I did:

```
outg_repeated = RepeatVector(32*32)(outg)
outg_reshaped = Reshape((32, 32, 256))(outg_repeated)
concatenated = Concatenate(axis=-1)([outm, outg_reshaped])
```

It gave desired shape of (None, 32, 32, 512), hovewer I do not know if I concatenated it properly, that is perpendicular to the Conv2D output, so my question is: Is it done right or did I overlooked something?

Comment: I'm not sure what the application of this is, but I can't imagine one where duplicating `outg` (via `RepeatVector`) 1024 times is correct. In terms of your problem, does it make sense to have the `Dense` output a tensor with a shape more amenable to `Concatenate`? Potentially output `(None, 32, 32)`? Its 4 times larger in terms of elements than `(None, 256)` but much more easily `Concatenate`d to `outm`.

Comment: It does not make sense, since for concatenation each dimension should be equal, except the axis you want to concat. For example you have (None,256) and (32,32,256) and want to merge them based on last axis. But what about the (32,32) and (None)? Unless you change the dimension in someway to make it proper for concatenation.

Comment: I am implementing network from "Let there be Color!: Joint End-to-end Learning of Global and Local Image Priors for Automatic Image Colorization with Simultaneous Classification"and I do not know why authors did it this way so I am just following the paper.

Comment: Interesting paper. You should really link it in the original question if you are attempting to recreate their work, especially when using verbiage to make it seem as if it is your original idea.

Comment: Provided AFAIK there is no canonical way to fuse dissimilarly shaped tensors with dissimilar features then whatever method that has sufficient support and evidence is appropriate. I don't have time to read the paper but I assume their motivation is to provide each mid-level pixel a "set" of global features to work with during colorization (the next set on convolutions).

Comment: I really do not need any suggestions on my work. I just want to know if it is done properly... What happened to this forum